# Tomcat WebDAV root directory

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to configure WebDAV in such a way that it serves content outside the root directory?

I basically want to serve content via WebDAV from an absolute path `C:\Content`. (A third party application will drop files in that directory.)

I'm running Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: This looks like the same question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833152/change-webdav-folder-on-tomcat/  Does it answer your question?